# blocked Access to geolocation was blocked over secure connection with mixed content to https://localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, geolocation, omniauth

I have implemented the `devise omniauth` setup and when I’m signed in with either Facebook, twitter or google the `html5 geolocation` returns a `position unavailable error`. But when I'm logged in as regular `devise user` it works just fine! How can I allow access to the `html5 geolocation` on my rails app when logged in with a social media account?

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie,showError);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}


function showError(error) {
switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        window.location = window.location;
        window.alert("Permission denied");
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        window.location = window.location;
        window.alert("Location information is unavailable.");
        break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        window.location = window.location;
        window.alert("The request to get user location timed out.");

        break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        window.location = window.location;
        window.alert("An unknown error occurred.");
        break;
}
location.reload();
}
```

**Update 1**

I changed the code to the following and I'm getting the following errors inside the browser console:

```
Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service
[blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over secure connection with mixed content to https://localhost:3000.


function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}


var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;

    console.log('Your current position is:');
    console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
    console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
    console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}
```

Any ideas on how to unblock this?

Comment: Are you running this on localhost? If not, your website is loading some assets from localhost via http, forcing the browser to decide the website is not secure, and refuses access to geolocation.
Also, this is a javascript issue, not a RoR issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tim Lawrenz. I'm running this on `https://localhost:3000` like this: `rails server puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=server.key&cert=server.crt'`. How can I figure out what is the exact issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a rails issue but a Javascript issue. Somewhere in your template, CSS, or Javascript you load something from http instead of https. Use your browser's inspector to find the culprit.